# Json deserealization to anonimous object Web-Api 2 C#

Tags: c#, json, веб-сервер, dapper

Имеется сервер Web-Api 2, который обращается к БД через dapper. На сервере имеется метод для вызова процедуры из БД, подобный этому:

```
var user = conn.Query<User>("spGetUser", **new { Id = 1 }**, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure)
```

Как видно из примера кода для передачи параметров используются анонимные типы.
На одном из контроллеров сервера есть метод Put принимающий в качестве параметров имя процедуры и передаваемые ей параметры:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IEnumerable<IEnumerable>> CallStoredProcedure(string ProcName, **[FromBody] object sqlParams**)
```

На клиенте есть метод вызывающий описанный выше метод с контроллера и передающий ему в качестве второго параметра анонимный класс вида:

```
new {Id = 5, Name = "default", price = 100}
```

**Количество и имена параметров заранее не известны.**

Проблема заключается в следующем, на контроллер приходит JObject хранящий в себе строку вида:

```
{{"Id":5}{"Name": default}{"price": 100}}
```

При попытке десереализовать данную строку средствами NewtonSoftJson получаем object содержащий в себе вышеупомянутый JObject. Десереализовать в анонимный класс не представляется возможности, т.к. тип объекта на сервере не известен. Передача без десереализцаии этой строки в даппер приводит к возврату null.
Много думали, много чего перепробовали, ничего не помогает. 
Буду очень признателен за любую реальную помощь. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а что это за апи такое, которое может принимать всё, что угодно? У вас есть контракт вашего АПИ или туда можно слать любую дичь?

Comment: А что такое контракт и как его сделать? Я недолго занимаюсь Web-Api опыта у меня не много и первый раз слышу про контракты.

Comment: `Десереализовать в анонимный класс не представляется возможности, т.к. тип объекта на сервере не известен`. Ну как бы язык то статический. Создается впечатление что вы пытаетесь это сделать с каким то JavaScript уклоном.

Comment: Уважаемы Vasek, я это прекрасно понимаю. Кто бы подсказал как мне передать анонимный тип через web-api

Comment: Контракт - это формальное описание вашего API, с примерами допустимых входных данных. Вот будете вы описывать свой метод `CallStoredProcedure`, что вы в описании и примерах укажете для параметра? Просто любой JSON?

Comment: Т.е. описание текстовое или описание в коде? Если чисто формальное текстовое то я вроде бы указал что туда передается анонимный объект вида: new {Id = 5, Name = "default", price = 100}. А если описание в коде , то если можно то поподробнее

Comment: IMHO - анонимный тип в данной ситуации не правильно. Что мешает обычный тип использовать?

Comment: Vasek , dapper принимает только анонимные типы в качестве параметров процедуры пллюс к этому мы не знаем какой типа захочет туда передать пользователь. Отказаться сейчас от использования dapper это значит переписать уйму уже готового протестированного кода и такую же уйму кода связанного с ним. Очень трудозатратный рефакторинг получится.

Comment: какая разница для вашего API какие типы принимает даппер? Пишите конкретный класс  с полями `Id, Name, price`, а имея в контроллере такой класс, вы уже догадаетесь, как с ним вызвать даппер или любую другую либо для доступа к БД

Comment: Так проблема в том, что процедур в БД может быть сотня и каждой будут свои параметры, я же не могу под каждую описывать классы на стороне клиента и сервера и делать методы.

Comment: ну то есть у вас получается не API приложения, а просто прослойка между браузером и БД. Тогда вы можете принимаеть JObject, разбирать его и строить [набор параметров динамичски](https://dapper-tutorial.net/parameter-dynamic). Но просто отмечу, что это плохая практика, когда клиенты практически напрямую вызывают методы из БД. API приложения, по идее, должно строить исходя из доменной логики.